# TTPhotoViewController rotate image but not the navigatione and tool bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20, ttphotoviewcontroller

I have made a subclass of TTPhotoViewController, wich when I Rotate iPhone also the current image is rotated but NOT The navigation bar and the toolbar (the bar with prev and next button).
In my subclass I have overide the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {   
    return  YES;
}
```

I've tried to overide willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration: e set up a breakpoint inside but seem that this method is never called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved as follow:

`TTPhotoViewController` was within a `TabBarController` and by default `TabBarController` doesn't return `YES` for `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`. So just subclass TabBarController and do something like that:

```
@implementation CustomTabBarController

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) interfaceOrientation {
    return [self.selectedViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
}

@end
```

I add a small detail: in my firts attempt to rotate the interface i've found that the `deviceOrientationDidChange:` in `TTScrollView.m` was commeted out, this is done because if you decomment this code the scroll view have a strange behaviour on landascape rotation.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all your view controllers i.e. Parent view controllers are allowing rotations.. most likely it is happening because one or more view controller is not returning TRUE for shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation